# rsync --recursive --ignore-existing: what (if any) additional flags are needed to resume/repair/overwrite any partially copied files?

Tags: shell, rsync, file-copy, corruption, integrity

Assume an `rsync --recursive --ignore-existing foo bar` copy command was being run for a large directory tree named `foo`, but that that command got prematurely interrupted. For example, because of a sudden power failure on the target machine.

Running the above command again can save a lot of time for any files/dirs already *fully* copied to the destination `bar`. But what about any file(s) that was right in the middle of being copied? Presumably, that file exists at the destination in an incomplete/broken state? Having it simply ignored as a "file that's already done" would be very undesirable, of course.

Does rsync handle this (extremely run of the mill) scenario intelligently without being directed to do so? (If so, how?)
Or does it only do so if specifically instructed by means of more or different flags?

Frustratingly, neither the man page nor any vaguely related questions or answers on this site seem to address this very important detail in a clear way. (Sorry if I just didn't look very well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-c` option to make rsync skip files by calculating and comparing their checksum instead of date and size:

```
-c, --checksum

skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size
```

That should copy all files again that doesn’t have the right contents.

You also have to remove the`--ignore-existing` flag, otherwise files that already exists on the destination will not be transferred.

Comment: Are you saying/implying that the `--ignore-existing` flag causes both *modification time* and *size in bytes* to be the criteria used to determine whether to skip? In that case, shouldn't that size check be sufficient as is? Or is there a scenario conceivable where the full exact amount of bytes were copied, but somehow became garbled nonetheless?

Comment: Maybe a good idea to include in this answer the full man text for the checksum flag rather than the abbreviated one liner summary. "--checksum, -c  This changes the way rsync checks if the files have been changed and are in need of a transfer. *Without this option, rsync uses a "quick check" that (by default) checks if each file's size and time of last modification match between the sender and receiver.*" (emphasis mine). In any case, thanks for nudging me in the right direction.

Comment: One more thing: should the `-c` flag be used *instead* of the `--ignore-existing` flag or in *addition* to that flag? (Maybe I'm just pedantic, but I feel that very explicit wording should be used when describing a detail this import.)

Comment: Yes, you have to remove the flag, I updated my answer.  Please upvote the answer if it helped you so others know. If you think it answered your question you should also mark it as accepted.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm still confused. I'll upvote and accept this answer as soon as my confusion has disappeared. I found this informative answer to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44353773/765294. However, if *modification time* and *size in bytes* are always checked *by default*, what is the point of the `--ignore-existing` flag? How is its inclusion any different from its omission?

Comment: If you include the flag it won’t update any file that already exists on the target regardless of the state of that file.

Comment: So instead of checking some combination of time/size/hash, it then only considers whether a file with the same name exists at the destination, right? Okay... then I'll need to remind myself to never use that flag again. Thanks.

Comment: So long story short: I conclude that in the majority of cases, one should specify *neither* `--ignore-existing` (due to complete lack of detection of file corruption) *nor* `--checksum` (because it's damn slow when dealing with large files on slow-ish volumes).